# Name of horizontal line below character in Hebrew

Tags: hebrew

Quick question about the Hebrew alphabet.

In the table below the sign with a single red line below is called PATAH.

What is the name of the sign with two red lines? How is it encoded in Unicode?

[image]

(The table is from the [cjhebrew manual](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/language/hebrew/cjhebrew/cjhebrew.pdf).)

Comment: I don't recognise that mark, and I can't find it in Unicode.= in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block))

Comment: Thanks @ColinFine - it's good to know I'm not missing something obvious!

Comment: My guess would be that it's still the patach, and there's a separate command just to let you position it better. Maybe ask at [tex.se]?

Comment: the use of : in the transliteration of sheva (and the hataf vowels) seems really weird given its similarity to the IPA symbol for long vowels

Comment: @Tristan But on the other hand, the symbol really is just two vertical dots.

Comment: @curiousdannii yeah, I can see where they're coming from, but for a phonetic transcription where something like IPA or X-SAMPA (or a modified version of either of them) would be expected it is a little confusing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That symbol represents the *furtive pataḥ* or [פתח גנוב](https://he.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%92%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91) - it says so right in the linked document: "The only exception is the *pataḥ furtivum* as in רוח"

There is no Unicode symbol for it, because it's typically (at least in Modern Hebrew) written identically to the normal *pataḥ*.  However, there are those who think it should be printed further to the right: [("Hebrew vowels: Furtive Patach")](https://forum.glyphsapp.com/t/hebrew-vowels-furtive-patach/9763/2) and so that option has been made available in the cjhebrew package.

See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443026/hebrew-vowel-positioning